# Thread ou Asynctask? Quando e qual devo usar?

Tags: android, thread, asynctask

Quando é recomendável o uso de `threads`?
Em que momento é aconselhável o uso do `AsyncTask`?
Gostaria de saber o que utilizar e que momento é preciso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*AsyncTask* é uma classe que facilita o uso de *threads* em conjugação com a *Main Thread*.

*AsyncTask* cria internamente uma *Thread* para executar o código declarado no método `doInBackground()` e um *handler* para colocar em execução na *Main Thread* o código declarado no método `onPostExecute()`.

Disponibiliza também uma forma de executar código na *Main Thread* enquanto o código em *background* é executado, usando `publishProgress()` para invocar o método `onProgressUpdate()`.

Assim, use *AsyncTask* para executar operações que durem poucos segundos<sup>(1)</sup> e cujo resultado deva ser usado pela *Main Thread*.

*AsyncTask* tem de ser criado e executado na *Main Thread* por isso use a classe *Thread* quando não for essa a situação, tiver que executar operações longas ou curtas quando não necessitar aceder à *Main Thread*.

Veja [aqui](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) outras alternativas como as classes *Executor*, *ThreadPoolExecutor* e *FutureTask*.

<sub>(1)</sub>
<sub>Esta restrição só se aplica se a *AsyncTask* for executada através do método [execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29). Esse método executa as *Tasks* de forma sequencial, numa única *thread*, fazendo com que a *Task* seguinte só inicialize após a finalização da anterior.

A restrição pode ser evitada usando o método [executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29), passado a ele um executor, normalmente AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, de forma a ser usada uma *pool* de *threads* para executar as tarefas em paralelo.</sub>