# AsyncTask Android

Tags: java, android, thread, background, asynctask

Tenho um método "Runnable" que executa em uma nova Thread um determinado método para atualizar minha lista.

Toda vez que chamo esse "Runnable", estou criando uma nova Thread, que pra mim isso não é muito positivo...

Como posso fazer a mesma coisa usando uma AsyncTask?

Segue meu método:

```
public void atualizaLista(){
    Thread t = new Thread("Thread1") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Atualiza lista
                    atualiza();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: A classe *AsyncTask* também cria uma nova *Thread*. [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68086/2541) dou uma pequena explicação entre escolher uma ou outra classe.

Answer (score 2):

**Leonardo**, é quase como matar um pombo com bazuca mas tente:

**`ExecutaTask.java`**

```
package com.seudominio.seuapp;

class ExecutaTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    /**
     * Ação como TIPO
     */
    public interface AcaoExecutaTask { void executa(); }
    private AcaoExecutaTask acao;

    public ExecutaTask(AcaoExecutaTask acao)
    {
        this.acao = acao;
    }

    /**
     * Antes de executar.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    /**
     * A ação.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {

        // Ação desejada aqui
        if(acao != null)
            acao.executa();

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Depois de executar.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

}
```

**Utilização**

```
// -- ação de executar (ahhh como no C# isto é bem mais fácil que no Java)
ExecutaTask.AcaoExecutaTask acao = new ExecutaTask.AcaoExecutaTask()
{
    @Override
    public void executa()
    {
        // Atualiza lista
        atualiza();
    }
};

new ExecutaTask(acao).execute();
```

Eu faria da classe `ExecutaTask.java` uma classe `static` para ser utilizada como "utilitário" para quaisquer ações.

**Dica**: Você pode implementar um `callback` facilmente usando a mesma ideologia de `public interface AcaoExecutaTask { void executa(); }`