# Login de usuário com WebService

Tags: android, http, login

Gostaria de pedir aos conhecedores de Java (Android) que me orientassem nesse código:

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TESTE", "Iniciou MainActivity");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    txt_usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
    txt_senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);
    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String user = txt_usuario.getText().toString();
            String pssw = txt_senha.getText().toString();

            SistemaHttp sHttp = new SistemaHttp(getBaseContext());
            String ret = sHttp.retornaUsuario(user, pssw);
            retornoLogin(ret);

        }
    });
}

private void retornoLogin(String retorno)
{
    Log.d("TESTE", "(MainActivity) retornoLogin(" + retorno + ")");
    if (retorno.equals("OK"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (retorno.equals("ERRO"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login incorreto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**SistemaHttp:**

```
public static final String SERVIDOR = "http://www.exemplo.com.br";
private static final String WEBSERVICE_URL = SERVIDOR + "/webservicesistema.php";

private Context mContext;

public SistemaHttp(Context ctx)
{
    mContext = ctx;
}

public String retornaUsuario(String user, String pssw)
{
    Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) retornaUsuario(" + user + ", " + pssw + ")");
    String met = "GET";
    String resp = "";

    try
    {
        if (enviarRequisicao(met, user, pssw))
        {
            resp = "OK";
            Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) retornaUsuario() enviarRequisicao(" + met + ", " + user + ", " + pssw + ") OK");
        }
        else
        {
            resp = "ERRO";
        }

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resp;
}

private boolean enviarRequisicao(String metodoHttp, String user, String pssw) throws Exception
{

    Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) enviarRequisicao(" + metodoHttp + ", " + user + ", " + pssw + ")");

    boolean sucesso = false;
    boolean doOutput = !"DELETE".equals(metodoHttp);
    String url = WEBSERVICE_URL;

    HttpURLConnection conexao = abrirConexao(url, metodoHttp, doOutput);

    if (doOutput)
    {
        OutputStream os = conexao.getOutputStream();
        os.write(loginToJsonBytes(user, pssw));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }

    int responseCode = conexao.getResponseCode();
    Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) enviarRequisicao() responseCode == " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) enviarRequisicao() responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK");
        InputStream is = conexao.getInputStream();
        String s = streamToString(is);
        is.close();
        // JSONObject json= new JSONObject(s);
        // hotel.idServidor = json.getInt("id");
        sucesso = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) enviarRequisicao() responseCode == HttpURLConnection.ERROR");
        sucesso = false;
    }

    conexao.disconnect();
    return sucesso;
}

private HttpURLConnection abrirConexao(String url, String metodo, boolean doOutput) throws Exception
{
    Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) abrirConexao(" + url + ", " + metodo + ", " + doOutput + ")");
    URL urlCon = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) urlCon.openConnection();
    conexao.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conexao.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conexao.setRequestMethod(metodo);
    conexao.setDoInput(true);
    conexao.setDoOutput(doOutput);

    if (doOutput)
    {
        conexao.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    conexao.connect();
    return conexao;
}

private byte[] loginToJsonBytes(String user, String pssw) {

    Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) loginToJsonBytes(" + user + ", " + pssw + ")");

    try {
        JSONObject jsonLogin = new JSONObject();
        jsonLogin.put("usuario", user);
        jsonLogin.put("senha", pssw);

        String json = jsonLogin.toString();

        return json.getBytes();
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    Log.d("TESTE", "(SistemaHttp) Iniciou streamToString()");

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int lidos;

    while ((lidos = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
    {
        baos.write(bytes, 0, lidos);
    }

    return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

A logica é a seguinte, ao clicar no botão pegar os valores que foram preenchidos nos `EditTexts` e enviar para o metodo `retornaUsuario(user, pssw)` da classe SistemaHttp, onde ela pega os dados e faz uma requisição HTTP para o webservice.php e retorna se existe o usuario e senha no banco de dados, e o metodo retornoLogin da MainActivity exibe um Toast de acordo com o retorno.

O trecho do `webservice.php` esta aqui:

```
$metodoHttp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($metodoHttp == 'GET') {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM hotel_db.usuarios WHERE login=? and senha=?");
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $endereco = $json->{'login'};
    $estrelas = $json->{'senha'};
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nome, $login);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $id = $conn->insert_id;
    $jsonRetorno = array("id"=>$id);
    echo json_encode($jsonRetorno);
}
```

Na parte do Android coloquei uns logs para ver ate onde o código rodava e ele chega ate o método `abrirConexao()` e aparece uma mensagem azul escrito:

> W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException W/System.err: at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>   W/System.err: at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>   W/System.err: at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>   W/System.err: at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.exemplo.exemplo.SistemaHttp.abrirConexao(SistemaHttp.java:122)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.exemplo.exemplo.SistemaHttp.enviarRequisicao(SistemaHttp.java:72)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.exemplo.exemplo.SistemaHttp.retornaUsuario(SistemaHttp.java:45)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.exemplo.exemplo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
>   W/System.err: at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>   W/System.err: at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) W/System.err:
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   W/System.err: at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A partir do Android 3.0](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), não são mais permitidas conexões de rede na *thread* principal (também conhecida como *UI Thread*). Operações de rede nessa *thread* têm o efeito de congelar a interface gráfica até que a requisição retorne um resultado, o que fornece uma péssima experiência de usuário.

Uma solução é fazer sua operação dentro de uma `AsyncTask`.

Não vou repetir como fazer isso, porque [aqui no StackOverflow em português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71855/asynctask-android) já temos uma explicação de como fazer. A [documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) também tem um exemplo fácil de entender. Caso enfrente dificuldades, fique à vontade para abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Valeu cara ja tinha ouvido falar na asyncTask mas nao tinha certeza de quando usar (nem onde) vou dar um apesquisada a mais e ver se consigo colocar ela no meu caso.