# Como funciona de fato o AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

Ainda, as vezes fico meio confuso com o `AsyncTask`. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {            
        return "Jon Snow";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

}
```

Confuso um pouco em relação em como deve ser tratado a questão dos argumentos como `AsyncTask<arg1, arg2, arg3>`. [Aqui tem várias perguntas e erros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=AsyncTask) em relação, mas não percebi nada que de fato explica seu funciona ou como deve usado. E o `doInBackground(String... params)`? Como funciona de fato o `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Existe uma explicação muito boa no SOen [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3)

Comment: @mercador se você conseguir trazer para o SOpt, muito provavelmente será recompensado por isso =D

Comment: A lição 3 desse curso explica perfeitamente tudo sobre AsyncTask: https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-networking--ud843/

Comment: Relacionado: [Thread ou Asynctask? Quando e qual devo usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68056/2541)

Answer (score 6):

`AsyncTask` é uma das classes que implementa [concorrência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorr%C3%AAncia_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) no **Android** e, basicamente,  auxilia outras classes como: [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html).

Atualmente, qualquer **evento** ou **modificação** que ocorre em um **aplicativo**, é gerenciado na **[Main Thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)** do OS. Isso significa que, por exemplo, se você realizar uma operação de longa duração na aplicação, como por exemplo, fazer o download de um arquivo, isso vai fazer com que a **Main Thread** seja **travada** até que sua ação esteja completa. Ou seja, o seu aplicativo vai ficar travado, o usuário não vai conseguir fazer nada nele, e só vai **destravar** quando o download do arquivo for concluído.

Uma **AsyncTask** evita justamente isso. Ela permite que você crie instruções no **background** e sincronize essas instruções com a **Thread Principal**, ou seja, o usuário vai poder continuar utilizando o aplicativo normalmente, ele não será travado e você também poderá atualizar a **UI** ao decorrer do processo.

Basicamente, essa classe não interfere na **Thread Principal**.

## **Argumentos**

A classe **AsyncTask** possui *3* *argumentos* para serem implementados, são eles:

```
AsyncTask<ParamsType, ProgressValue, ResultValue> {}
```

- **ParamsType**: É o tipo do **parâmetro** que será enviado para a instrução. Este parâmetro será enviado ao método `doInBackground()`.
- **ProgressValue**: Como o próprio nome diz, é o tipo do valor do progresso da nossa **instrução**. Ele mostrará o progresso atual do que estamos tentando realizar.
- **ResultValue**: É o tipo do resultado final que receberemos na nossa **instrução**. É o resultado como um todo. Ele é retornado do método `doInBackground()`.

## **Métodos**

> **doInBackground()**

Este método é responsável por duas coisas. A primeira, ele é responsável por receber o tipo de parâmetro que você deseja ter como resultado e a segunda, ele é responsável pelo código que irá executar a nossa instrução. Por exemplo, se desejamos fazer um **HttpRequest**, esse método ficará responsável pelo bloco de código do **HttpRequest** e, finalmente, após executar todo o nosso código, ele vai **retornar um valor**, que é o **resultado** que desejamos ver. Se queremos como resultado uma `String`, ele retornará uma `String` que será enviada ao método **onPostExecute**.

> **onPostExecute()**

Este método é chamado após o término das instruções no método **doInBackground**, ou seja, quando tudo estiver completo no método doInBackground, quando já tivermos recebido o parâmetro que desejamos receber, o método OnPostExecute será chamado e ele irá mostrar o resultado ao usuário, se caso você desejar. Ele recebe o parâmetro que você definiu na classe.

> **Exemplo**

```
class MTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... result) {
       // Http....
       return mHttpResponse;
   } 

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String resultValue) {
       new Toast.makeText(context, resultValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

**Links Úteis**: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute()

Answer (score 5):

A documentação oficial está bem explicada em:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Mas basicamente, o AsyncTask é feito para rodar tarefas em background para não onerar a performance da thread principal ou UI (user interface) ou mesmo travá-la. Exemplos de processamentos em background: baixar dados da internet, decodificar imagens, etc.

Quanto aos 3 parâmetros (arg1, arg2 e arg3)

- arg1 - Tipo de dado que será utilizado como input do processamento (pode não ter nenhum ou pode ser mais de um)
- arg2 - Tipo de dado que será retornado durante o processamento (se necessário. Ex: exibir progresso do processamento)
- arg3 - Tipo de dado que será retornado após o processamento (pode não ter nenhum).

O método doInBackground() é onde você define o que será processado em background e precisa receber parâmetros do mesmo tipo definido em arg1 e retornar um valor do mesmo tipo definido em arg3. Os parâmetros são acessados pelo array param[]. Se só tiver um, por exemplo, será o param[0].

O método onPostExecute() pega o valor retornado pelo método acima (que é o argumento "result") e repassa para a thread principal (UI), então você pode exibir uma mensagem com o dado, setar um TextView, exibir a imagem processada, etc.

Os outros 2 métodos são opcionais:

- onPreExecute() - Se quiser fazer alguma coisa antes do processamento começar
- onProgressUpdate() - retorna um valor intermediário para a UI do mesmo tipo definido em arg2. Opcional. Ex: status de progresso.

Uma vez definido tudo, só iniciar a execução. Ex:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }

DownloadFilesTask task = new DownloadFilesTask();
task.execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Comment: Acho legal também deixar registrado aqui que além do AsyncTask, também existem bibliotecas que trabalham com Jobs em background, encapsulando algumas coisas bem chatas de fazer como Scheduling ou Retry Strategies, além do que deixando mais fácil as chamadas

Já usei:

Evernote: http://evernote.github.io/android-job/
Job Queue: https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue