# Qual é a forma correta de usar o RunOnUiThread() no Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Quando eu preciso atualizar um campo na UI, eu preciso rodar esse código na UI *thread*?

Por exemplo: tenho que alterar o layout da minha *activity*.

O código que estou usando é esse:

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    _layoutBlurred.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    _layoutBlurred.Background = image;
    _layoutContent.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    _listViewScheduling.Enabled = false;
});
```

Ou até mesmo uma simples troca de texto de um TextView:

```
_txtStatus.Text = GetString(Resource.String.app_online);
```

É necessário usar o **`RunOnUiThread()`** nestes casos ou não?

Comment: Você tem que utilizar RunOnUiThread, mas acho que existe um conceito mais inteligente para isto que é o AsyncTasks, depois da uma olhada neste link: http://www.devmedia.com.br/asynctask-trabalhando-com-tarefas-assincronas/29823

Comment: Tem uma outra pergunta que fala mais a respeito de AsyncTask, acho que se adapta mais neste seu cenário! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68056/thread-ou-asynctask-quando-e-qual-devo-usar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é necessário.

Componentes declarados e exibidos na UI *vivem* na UI e estão operando na *thread* da UI.

Acessar estes componentes de outra thread violaria a *thread-safety*. Por isto este método é necessário.

Há **outros** casos que *parecem* que causam a necessidade de usar o método `RunOnUiThread`, mas na verdade não há essa necessidade

**Exemplo:**

```
btActivate.Click += async delegate 
{
    bool x = await Foo.ActivateAsync();
    txtResult.Text = x ? "Successful" : "Failed";
};
```

Neste caso, o `delegate` assíncrono atribuído ao evento `click` do botão já está na thread da UI, porque ele é invocado na `thread` do controle que ele foi associado. E quando o método assíncrono `ActivateAsync` retorna, ele é resumido na thread da UI, e o melhor de tudo é que ele não trava a thread da UI enquanto ele é executado, pois ele é aguardado assincronamente com a keyword `await`.

Answer (score -3):

Atualmente utilize Xamarin Essentials

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
            
});
```